# Some questions about Simple Past and Past Perfect Tense

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

I have some blank fillings here making me mad and confused.

**__he__(know) her for a long time before they __(get) married?**

My answer is: Had he known her for a long time before they got married ?

**He __(drive) down the hotel where they __(spend) their honeymoon years ago**

My answer is: He drove down the hotel where they had spent their honeymoon years ago.

**When we __(get) to the station the train __(already/leave)**

My answer is: When we got to the station, the train has already left.

**He __ (sit) at a table by the window where he __(have) a meal with Jane.**

My answer is: He sat at a table by the window where he had had a meal with Jane.

I wonder if I had done them correctly, or there're some mistakes. Please help and thank you for much!

Comment: It's really not fair to dump this on us as a question. That would make us teachers correcting your homework. What specific question do you have other than having us read (which is a laborious job) through all those questions and your answers? One hint: the already one is wrong for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your first, second and last answers are correct.

As for the third, the correct answer is:

> When we got to the station, the train **had** already left.